# Calculating the frequency of strings as they get stored in a nested hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

i want to write a code that stores strings in a hashmap as they are read from text files.

i have written the code below and it works, no errors, the frequency of every occurrence of the string combination does not change, it is always 1.

i am asking for assistance on how i can ensure that if a string combination appears more than once in the text file then its frequency should also increase.

this is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;



   public class NgramBetaC {

    static String[] hashmapWord = null;
    public static Map<String,Map<String, Integer>> bigrams = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {       

    //prompt user input
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //read words from collected corpus; a number of .txt files

     File directory = new File("Corpus4");
     File[] listOfFiles = directory.listFiles();//To read from all listed iles in the "directory"

            //String bWord[] = null;
            int lineNumber = 0;
            String line;
            String files;
            String delimiters = "[\\s+,?!:;.]";
            int wordTracker = 0;

            //reading from a list of text files 
            for (File file : listOfFiles) {
                if (file.isFile()) {
                    files = file.getName();
                    try {
                        if (files.endsWith(".txt") || files.endsWith(".TXT")) {  //ensures a file being read is a text file 

                       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)); 


                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                                line = line.toLowerCase();
                                hashmapWord = line.split(delimiters);

                        for(int s = 0; s < hashmapWord.length - 2; s++){

                                    String read = hashmapWord[s];
                                    String read1 = hashmapWord[s + 1];
                                    final String read2 = hashmapWord[s + 2];

                                    String readBigrams = read + " " + read1;

                                    final Integer count = null;

                                    //bigrams.put(readBigrams, new HashMap() {{ put (read2, (count == null)? 1 : count + 1);}});
                                    bigrams.put(readBigrams, new HashMap<String, Integer>());
                                    bigrams.get(readBigrams).put(read2, (count == null) ? 1 : count+1);


                                } br.close();
                        }
                        }
                    } catch (NullPointerException | IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        System.out.println("Unable to read files: " + e);
                    }

            }       
          }
          }
```

THE LINES CONTAINED IN THE TEXT FILES ARE::

1.i would like some ice cream.
2.i would like to be in dubai this december.
3.i love to eat pasta.
4.i love to prepare pasta myself.
5.who will be coming to see me today?

THE OUTPUT I GET WHEN PRINTING CONTENTS OF THE HASHMAP IS:

{coming to={see=1}, would like={to=1}, in dubai={this=1}, prepare pasta={myself=1}, to eat={pasta=1}, like to={be=1}, to prepare={pasta=1}, will be={coming=1}, love to={prepare=1}, some ice={cream=1}, be in={dubai=1}, be coming={to=1}, dubai this={december=1}, to be={in=1}, i love={to=1}, to see={me=1}, who will={be=1}, like some={ice=1}, i would={like=1}, see me={today=1}}

> > Please assist! some string combinations are not even appearing.

THE OUTPUT I EXPECT AS I READ FROM THE FILES IS:

{coming to={see=1}, would like={to=1}, in dubai={this=1}, prepare pasta={myself=1}, to eat={pasta=1}, like to={be=1}, to prepare={pasta=1}, will be={coming=1}, love to={prepare=1}, some ice={cream=1}, be in={dubai=1}, be coming={to=1}, dubai this={december=1}, to be={in=1}, i love={to=1}, to see={me=1}, who will={be=1}, like some={ice=1}, i would={like=2}, see me={today=1}, love to {eat=1}, would like {some=1}, i would {love=1}, would love {to=1}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tentatively update the current structure without overwriting the originl content

Replace

```
bigrams.put(readBigrams, new HashMap<String, Integer>());
bigrams.get(readBigrams).put(read2, (count == null) ? 1 : count+1);
```

With

```
HashMap<String, Integer> counter = bigrams.get(readBigrams);
if (null == counter) {
    counter = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    bigrams.put(readBigrams, counter);
}
Integer count = counter.get(read2);
counter.put(read2, count == null ? 1 : count + 1);
```

Comment: now, i want to be able to access these frequencies in order to calculate the probability. can you help me on how i can write such a code. for example; one of the key pairs in the hashmap is "would like={to=1, some=1}". from this i want to be able to tell how many times does the string "to" or "some" follow the string "would like" and in such a way determining the probability.